# how to implement lambda-calculus in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, lambda-calculus

In OCaml, it seems that "fun" is the binding operator to me. Does OCaml have built-in substitution? If does, how it is implemented? is it implemented using de Bruijn index?

Just want to know how the untyped lambda-calculus can be implemented in OCaml but did not find such implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml does not perform normal-order reduction and uses call-by-value semantics. [Some terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_normal_form#Reduction_strategies) of lambda calculus have a normal form than cannot be reached with this [evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).

See [The Substitution Model of Evaluation](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2013sp/lectures/lec06-subst-model/lec06.html), as well as [How would you implement a beta-reduction function in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4039494/124319).

Comment: That means the user must implement substitutions explicitly. I suppose most functional programming languages are the same: do not perform beta-reduction. Thank you.

Comment: More precisely: beta reduction says *how* you apply functions, but not *when*. You need a reduction strategy and the one usually done is eager and might never terminates for some terms, even though those have a normal form.

Comment: so you saying substitutions are handled by the language, but the user needs to implement reduction strategy?  I am only interested in how the language applies functions.

Comment: Languages defines how and when terms are evaluated, which includes how functions are applied. I am not sure who the "user" is supposed to be in your question, but if you want to implement lambda calculus with OCaml and encode lambda with `fun` directly, you are going to inherit the evaluation order of OCaml (the one I linked). But if you need to do another kind of reduction, you have to make an interpreter for this and for your own abstract syntax tree. [This summary](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hudak/CS201S08/lambda.pdf) will certainly explain those things better than me.

Answer (score 5):

As Bromind, I also don't exactly understand what you mean by saying "Does OCaml have built-in substitution?"

About lambda-calculus once again I'm not really understand but, if you talking about writing some sort of lambda-calculus interpreter then you need first define your "syntax":

```
(* Bruijn index *)
type index = int

type term =
  | Var of index
  | Lam of term
  | App of term * term
```

So `(λx.x) y` will be `(λ 0) 1` and in our syntax `App(Lam (Var 0), Var 1)`.

And now you need to implement your reduction, substitution and so on. For example you may have something like this:

```
(* identity substitution: 0 1 2 3 ... *)
let id i = Var i

(* particular case of lift substitution: 1 2 3 4 ... *)
let lift_one i = Var (i + 1)

(* cons substitution: t σ(0) σ(1) σ(2) ... *)
let cons (sigma: index -> term) t = function
  | 0 -> t
  | x -> sigma (x - 1)

(* by definition of substitution:
       1)  x[σ] = σ(x)
       2)  (λ t)[σ] = λ(t[cons(0, (σ; lift_one))])
               where (σ1; σ2)(x) = (σ1(x))[σ2]
       3)  (t1 t2)[σ] = t1[σ] t2[σ]
*)
let rec apply_subs (sigma: index -> term) = function
  | Var i -> sigma i
  | Lam t -> Lam (apply_subs (function
                              | 0 -> Var 0
                              | i -> apply_subs lift_one (sigma (i - 1))
                             ) t)
  | App (t1, t2) -> App (apply_subs sigma t1, apply_subs sigma t2)
```

As you can see OCaml code is just direct rewriting of definition.

And now small-step reduction:

```
let is_value = function
  | Lam _ | Var _ -> true
  | _ -> false

let rec small_step = function
  | App (Lam t, v) when is_value v ->
     apply_subs (cons id v) t
  | App (t, u) when is_value t ->
     App (t, small_step u)
  | App (t, u) ->
     App (small_step t, u)
  | t when is_value t ->
     t
  | _ -> failwith "You will never see me"

let rec eval = function
  | t when is_value t -> t
  | t -> let t' = small_step t in
         if t' = t then t
         else eval t'
```

For example you can evaluate `(λx.x) y`:

```
eval (App(Lam (Var 0), Var 1))
- : term = Var 1
```

Comment: By "built-in substitution", I mean do we not need to implement substitution? or The language provides it implicitly.  As seen from your answer, you used de Bruijn, explicitly implemented substitutions and so on. Some languages provide bindable types and implicit substitutions for such types. That is what I was asking.  However, Bromind's answer is using "fun", which seems do not ask the user to define substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you mean by saying "Does OCaml have built-in substitution? ...", but concerning how the lambda-calculus can be implemented in OCaml, you can indeed use `fun` : just replace all the lambdas by `fun`, e.g.:
for the church numerals: you know that `zero = \f -> (\x -> x)`, `one = \f -> (\x -> f x)`, so in Ocaml, you'd have

```
let zero = fun f -> (fun x -> x)
let succ = fun n -> (fun f -> (fun x -> f (n f x)))
```

and `succ zero` gives you `one` as you expect it, i.e. `fun f -> (fun x -> f x)` (to highlight it, you can for instance try `(succ zero) (fun s -> "s" ^ s) ("0")` or `(succ zero) (fun s -> s + 1) (0)`).

As far as I remember, you can play with `let` and `fun` to change the evaluation strategy, but to be confirmed...

---

N.B.: I put all parenthesis just to make it clear, maybe some can be removed.

Comment: I find one implementation, it uses de Bruijn indices to implement lambda-calculus. I don't think your programs run directly, could you provide the code if there is a way of implementing as you presented?

Comment: What I presented is just a way to "run" lambda terms, with a mechanical substitution of `\ ` s by `fun`s. If you want to do this translating automatically, something like `perl -pe 's/\\\\/fun\ /g' term.l > term.ml` should work, assuming your term is in `term.l`.

Answer (score 1):

I still do not have enough points to answer to Vonaka's solution, but this one is wrong. First, the "Var 1" term is not really correct in de Bruijin's index notation, because free variables should match be decremented when the beta reduction of "App (Lam (Var 0), Var 1))" is done. The reduction of "App (Lam (Var 0), Var 1))" should be "Var 0". If you are not convinced with this, here is a little example of what happens :
`λx.(λy.y)x` is `λ0.(λ1).0` which is, with this implementation

```
 Lam (App (Lam (Var 0), Var 1))
```

But if we reduce `λx.(λy.y)x` we get `λx.x` which is `λ0`, or `Lam (Var 0)` with this implementation.
But sadly :

```
utop # eval (Lam (App (Lam (Var 0), Var 1))) ;; 
- : term = Lam (App (Lam (Var 0), Var 1))
```

The term does not reduce. This is because a `λx. ...` term is not necessary in normal form, because of this rule (which is included in the definition of β-reduction) :
[the rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etnak.png)

But even if you change the function to check if a term is normal or not, you will face big problems because the free variables do not decrease when reducing. Here is a good implementation which works with a normalizing strategy :

```ml
type lambda = 
    | V of int 
    | L of lambda 
    | A of (lambda * lambda)

let ind (l : lambda) : int -> lambda =  (fun v -> if v = 0 then l else V (pred v))

let rec lift_i (i : int) (n : int) (l : lambda) : lambda = 
    match l with
    | V k -> if k < i then l else V (k + n)
    | L t -> L (lift_i (succ i) n t)
    | A (l1, l2) -> A ( lift_i i n l1, lift_i i n l2) 

let lift (n : int) (l : lambda) = lift_i 0 n l

let rec subst_i (i : int) (env : int -> lambda) (l : lambda) : lambda = 
    match l with
    | V k -> if k < i then l else lift i (env (k-i))
    | L t -> L (subst_i (succ i) env t)
    | A (l1, l2) -> A (subst_i i env l1, subst_i i env l2)

let subs  (env : int -> lambda) (l : lambda) : lambda = subst_i 0 env l

let rec is_beta_normal (l : lambda) : bool = 
    match l with
    | V _ -> true
    | L x -> is_beta_normal x
    | A (L _, _) -> false
    | A (l1, l2) -> is_beta_normal l1 && is_beta_normal l2

(*
Looks for rules in this order : 
1) β
2) cong1
3) cong2
4) ξ
*)

let rec beta_red (l : lambda) : lambda = 
    match l with
    | A (L t,l2) -> subs (ind l2) t 
    | A (t, v) when is_beta_normal t -> A (t, beta_red v)
    | A (t, v) -> A (beta_red t, v)
    | L t  when not (is_beta_normal t) -> L (beta_red t)
    | _ -> l
```

This implementation is taken from https://github.com/JeanGalte/lambda, which properly implements untyped lambda calculus and provides a sandbox for terms manipulation with de Bruijin's indexes.